# Google Play Billing 5 - How to get the base price for subscriptions when you have multiple offers?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

With the Billing 5 library, Google introduces Base plans, offers, and pricing phases. Many new things to digest...

I want to display only the base plan price for all the subscriptions.

From what I can see, the only way to get the offers, respectively prices, is by calling `getSubscriptionOfferDetails()`

```
List<SubscriptionOfferDetails> subscriptionOfferDetailsList = productDetails.getSubscriptionOfferDetails();
```

It's not clear to me how to identify if an offer is a 'base plan'. I don't see a `productDetails.getBasePlans()` nor a `subscriptionOfferDetails.isBasePlan()`

**I just want to get the price of the subscription from the base plan. What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer, but I'm not sure it's the best approach. The code below iterates through all the offers and returns the first base plan by checking if `offerId` is null.

```
    for(int j=0;j<subscriptionOfferDetailsList.size();j++){
        ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails subscriptionOfferDetails = subscriptionOfferDetailsList.get(j);
        if(subscriptionOfferDetails.getOfferId() == null){
            return subscriptionOfferDetails;
        }
    }
```